# Rails 5 many to many index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, join, consul

I am having a problem in the eyes when presenting the data.

I have 3 user models, sponsors and pets Result that sponsors in a table join between users and pets that are nan, my problem is in the hour to show all the sponsors of the mascot in sight and achievement but in a wrong way to La time to msotrar the data. I hope you can tell me how to fix it. Thank you.

Index.html.erb

```
<h1>Sponsors#index</h1>

 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="histories">
     <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Mascota</th>
        <th>Padrinos</th>
        <th>Apadrinar</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
     <% @pets.each do |pet| %>
         <tr>
             <td><%= pet.name %></td>
             <td>
                 <% @users.each do |user| %>
                     <% @sponsors.each do |sponsor| %>
                         <% if user.id == sponsor.user_id and pet.id == sponsor.pet_id %>
                             <%= user.email%>
                         <% else %>
                             <p>No Tengo Padinos =-( </p>
                         <% end %>
                     <% end %>
                 <% end %>
              </td>
              <td><button>Apadrinar</button></td>
         </tr>
      <% end %>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

My controller has the three models that I am sending to view.

```
def index
 @sponsors = Sponsor.all
 @users = User.all
 @pets = Pet.all
end
```

pet.rb

```
class Pet < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :adoptions
 belongs_to :race, required: false
 has_many :users, through: :sponsors
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :pets, through: :sponsors
end
```

sponsor.rb

```
class Sponsor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :pet
end
```

The output that now shows me the attachment in the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9Mrr.png)

I also wonder if there is a better way to make the query, to show the respective data.

Another thing is how would I do to no longer be able to sponsor pets that I have already given a sponsor?

Comment: What do your models look like? If Sponsor is a join table you can say in Pet `has_one :user, through: :sponsor`. Then, in your view you could loop through `@pets` and read `pet.user`. Use `if pet.user.any?` for your if/else statement.

Comment: Models added, for better apreciattion.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a through table to join users and pets, but your associations aren't setup properly. For a through model, you have to have_many of the through table along with a has_many: :through association. Your associations should look like this:

```
class Pet < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :adoptions
 belongs_to :race, required: false
 **has_many :sponsors**
 has_many :users, through: :sponsors
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
 **has_many :sponsors**
 has_many :pets, through: :sponsors
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Afther working and following diferent recomendations here is my solution.

```
<% @pets.each do |pet| %>
 <tr>
  <td><a href="<%= pet_path(pet) %>"> <%= pet.name %></a></td>
  <td>
    <% if pet.sponsors.any? %>
     <% pet.sponsors.each do |sponsor| %>
      | <%= sponsor.user_email %> |
     <% end %>
    <% else %>
     <p>No Tengo Padinos =-( </p>
    <% end %>
   </td>
   <td>
    <%= link_to "Apadrinar", {:controller => "sponsors", :action => "new", :mascot => pet.id }%>
   </td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

I changed also my models.

sponsor.rb

```
class Sponsor < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :pet
 has_many :gifts
 delegate :email, to: :user, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :sponsors
 has_many :pets, through: :sponsors
end
```

pet.rb

```
class Pet < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :sponsors
 has_many :users, through: :sponsors
end
```

And finally mi index on Controller.

sponsors_controller.rb

```
def index
 # @sponsors = Sponsor.all
 # @users = User.all
 # @pets = Pet.all
 # @pets_no_sponsors = Pet.where.not(id: Sponsor.select("pet_id")).select("id")
 @pets = Pet.includes(:sponsors)
end
```

By making a delegation now I only make a query which sends everything necessary to my index.